# Unable to locate package openjdk-14-jdk, Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: apt, 20.04, asus, eclipse, openjdk

I am trying to install openjdk-14-jdk required for install the Eclipse IDE, but it returns "E: Unable to locate package openjdk-14-jdk". There is no recommendation when I click TAB at "sudo apt install -y openjdk-". How can I fix it? Thank you!

[image]

I was following the instruction here:
[image]

Comment: There is no such package in Ubuntu repos. You can ask those who wrote the manual.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can install the default JDK by

```
sudo apt install default-jdk
```

The manual is wrong for Ubuntu.